# Not able to open print setup in my mac. I use OS X EI Captain 10.11.1

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, printing, airprint

I am not able to open print setup.
When I Open Print Queue, i get the following screen[image: Open Print Queue Image]

I am not even able to given double sided printout.

Please help me out

Basically, I want to give back to back printout. But I am not getting that option at all.. In print setup, when choose Layout, the "two sided" dropdown is greyed out as shown below. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but I think you're just looking in the wrong place. The Printers & Scanners control panel is a 'set & forget' control, one you really only need if you add a new printer.

You deal with the regular task of adjusting printer defaults for a given print job from the Print menu in your current application - this example from Safari

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I want to give two-sided printouts. I don't get that option anywhere. I have edited in my question. Please check. "Two-sided" dropdown is greyed out.